# Как в Pages преобразовать текст вверхний регистр?

Tags: macos

1) Собственно преобразовать я его умею - `Правка->Преобразования->Верхний регистр`. А как назначит для этого горячую клавишу?

2) В Word для копирования формата и передачи его другой части текста, используется значок "кисточка". А как в Pages реализовать подобный функционал?

Comment: Системные настройки -> Клавиатура -> Клавиатурные сокращения -> Pages
Примерно так (Mac'а под рукой нет)

Comment: Спасибл! У меня получилось. А нас счет второго вопроса - известно что-нибудь?

Comment: Посмотрю, когда зарядник для ноутбука придет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Системные настройки → Клавиатура → Сочетание клавиш → App Shortcuts
Жмем плюс, пишем точное название команды в меню, назначаем сочетание клавиш.
Можно выбрать "Все программы", тогда команда будет работать везде, где есть такая команда в  меню.

2) ПКМ на "Текстовый блок", потом на "+". Можно задать название.
Выделяешь текст, а после выбираешь только что сохраненный для него стиль.
[image: Скриншот]

[image: Скриншот 2]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Cmd-Shift-+

Или перетяните кнопку в панель инструментов [image]

Comment: Так это же надстрочный текст, а не ВЕРХНИЙ РЕГИСТР.